# Сложение нулевых volatile переменных выводит не ноль

Tags: c++

Есть следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>

volatile int a;

int main() {
  std::cout << a + a;
}
```

Почему выводится ненулевое значение?!

Comment: Как и чем компилируете?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111591/discussion-on-question-by-genious-----).

Comment: А почему собственно должно быть 0?

Comment: @Qwertiy, потому что глобальные переменные инициализируются нулём (zero-initialize)?

Comment: @wololo тут разве не UB из-за unsequenced доступа к volatile переменной в `a+a`?

Comment: @dIm0n, вы правы! Мой предыдущий комментарий, про то, что будет выведен ноль — ошибочен! Поведение приведённой программы действительно не определено. Ваш комментарий заслуживает изложения отдельным ответом.

Comment: Автор, все же напишите на каких OS, CPU и версии компилятора вы наблюдаете такое поведение?

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я понимаю, у программы неопределённое поведение из-за выражения `a + a`, поэтому может выводить как 0, так и всё что угодно, либо не выводить ничего. Это следует из цитат:

> 1. Reading an object designated by a volatile glvalue ... are all side
>    effects.
> 2. If a side effect on a memory location is unsequenced relative to
>    either another side effect on the same memory location or a value
>    computation using the value of any object in the same memory location,
>    and they are not potentially concurrent, the behavior is undefined.

Источник: http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution.

Comment: А вы смогли воспроизвести такое поведение? (минус не мой)

Comment: @avp не 0? - gcc последний не воспроизводит, больше не проверял